# Get Facebook Access Token in unity3d Desktop App

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-unity-sdk

I am new in unity3d and i am trying to create an app with social connect for unity3d desktop app.I read some tutorial like [unity-and-facebook](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/03/26/unity-and-facebook-are-now-in-a-relationship-and-its-awesome/). My problem is how to get an access token of user.I follow same steps as i read [getting-started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/) on facebook. When facebook-unity package import to my new package and change app id from facebook setting.**I am getting a default access token** and dummy user logedin.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid we don't directly support desktop applications at the moment. If you are testing in the editor we put dummy data in to help with testing, but you must run your app on apps.facebook.com/, or run it on ios or android.

Comment: Is there a way to access facebook with a Unity desktop/standalone application ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm studying this solution recently,
I Got a solution form this page

http://www.ifc0nfig.com/accessing-facebook-unity-game-2/

The addition condition is that you may have to setup a webpage to parse the authorize code.
Then your desktop app can get the code form the webpage you setup.