# Must i use facebook canvas to login on my unity web player game?

Tags: facebook, canvas, authentication, unity-game-engine

I have a unity web player game that i would like add facebook login to.
I downloaded the sdk and it works fine on the unity editor.

I want to login using facebook without being on the facebook canvas, is it even possible?
If it is, i would very much like to know how.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/canvas), setting up an app in the Developer Console with Facebook is part of the setup process for using the official Facebook Unity SDK.

I can understand why it would be nice to be able to use the FB Login for Unity web player games hosted on other game web sites.

I looked in the Facebook usage policy document in the Login section, and although Facebook says native iOS and Android apps should use the official FB SDK for each platform, it makes no mention of the Unity SDK.

But [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670006/get-facebook-access-token-in-unity3d-desktop-app) says "you must run your app on apps.facebook.com/, or run it on ios or android." It sounds like the poster is part of the Facebook team.